# Entity Framework 6 Ignoring Distinct in SQL Query when Selecting Multiple Columns

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am not seeing the expected SQL generated with regard to `Distinct` when selecting multiple columns.  In particular the `Distinct` is being left out of the generated SQL.  Strangely, this seems to work properly when my `Select` clause only has 1 column.  How do I achieve a `Distinct` SQL query using Entity Framework when selecting multiple columns?  `Group By` also does not work when the key is multiple columns.

In these examples, "e" is my `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

Query that selects multiple columns ignores distinct:

```
var distinct1 = e.MyViews
                 .Select(a => new { a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3, })
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

Generated SQL is missing `Distinct`:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Col1] AS [Col1], 
    [Extent1].[Col2] AS [Col2], 
    [Extent1].[Col3] AS [Col3]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [MyView].[Col1] AS [Col1], 
         [MyView].[Col2] AS [Col2], 
         [MyView].[Col3] AS [Col3], 
         [MyView].[UserId] AS [UserId]
     FROM 
         [MySchema].[MyView] AS [MyView]) AS [Extent1]
```

Query that selects single column uses `Distinct`:

```
var distinct2 = e.MyViews
                 .Select(a => new { a.Col1, })
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

The generated SQL correctly includes `Distinct`:

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Distinct1].[Col1] AS [Col1]
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         [Extent1].[Col1] AS [Col1], 
         1 AS [C1]
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              [MyView].[Col1] AS [Col1], 
              [MyView].[Col2] AS [Col2], 
              [MyView].[Col3] AS [Col3], 
              [MyView].[UserId] AS [UserId]
          FROM 
              [MySchema].[MyView] AS [MyView]) AS [Extent1]) AS [Distinct1]
```

Note that this is running on .Net Framework 4.8 and is the original EF 6, not EF Core.

Running against SQL Server (Azure SQL Database Managed Instance).

I have confirmed that EF Core correctly injects Distinct in the generated SQL with multiple columns in the Select, but that doesn't really help me with my .Net Framework project.

**Update**

I am now finding that some combinations of columns in the Select clause do work, while others do not, but I cannot determine what the differentiating factor is.

These combinations of columns in Select do produce Distinct in SQL:
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col1, Col2
Col2, Col3

These combinations of columns in Select do not produce Distinct in SQL:
Col1, Col3
Col1, Col2, Col3

Comment: Distinct works in Entity Framework 6. You'll have to provide more information. What is `e`? How is it configured? Is the PK or any unique index or constraint composed by those columns? If the columns are unique there's no reason to use DISTINCT

Comment: Also, Entity Framework 6 or EF Core 6? What database are you using? The SQL query is created by the database provider, not EF itself. Some providers are smarter than others

Comment: Despite what the SQL comes back with, are the results distinct or not? It may be that EF thinks in some cases it might be more efficient to do in memory. Is this with a clean DBContext with no entities loaded/tracked? Normally when looking for distinct sets of values from a table/view it is better to use GroupBy rather than Distinct. Another question would by why the SELECT is selecting a UserID if that is not in your `Select` expression.

Comment: @StevePy, group by is also getting ignored for this case.  This is a clean DBContext that was instantiated just before running the select.  The results of the query are absolutely not distinct.  It is returning thousands of records, where the correct distinct would produce less than 100.

Comment: This requires a [mre] because we need to see everything that is involved, esp. data types, unique indexes and EF's mappings. If EF has any information in its model that the queried combination is surely unique it won't add Distinct.